# Inserting invoice transactions with Dynamics AX / Axapta Business Connector

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

G'day,

OK, I have now rewritten this question totally:

I am trying to import data into Dynamics through the use of the Business Connector (ideally, I would be importing it directly through SQL but I understand that is not a good idea - however I am open to other suggestions).  This is to import invoices from a production system into Dynamics / Axapta (v5).

I can code to insert data into the CUSTINVOICETABLE table, which works fine and generates the RECID.  However, new invoices just inserted exist without an Invoice ID (until they are posted I understand). However, I need to insert line items into the CUSTINVOICETRANS table as children of the above entry.  For this you need to set the INVOICEID field to refer the above as the link to the parent. However, this does not appear possible before the invoice has been posted.  Or I may be way off track?

Does anyone have any ideas or can shed any light for me?  That would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Steve

Comment: Are you sure you have to insert in the table `CustInvoiceLine` rather than `CustInvoiceTrans`?
The table `CustInvoiceLine` is used in "Free text invoice" only.

Comment: Hi Jan B, for me this is trial and error. I have checked this out and am left wondering how to link this to the CUSTINVOICETABLE - as this seems to use INVOICEID as the parent key, but at that point I do not have a value for the invoice number. Any ideas? Thx!

Comment: The tables `CustInvoiceJour` and `CustInvoiceTrans` is for invoices, which by defenition already have been posted. As you do not seem to have an invoice number, this is not the case. Could you on a higher level describe what you are trying to do? Is it a sales order? Has it been posted or not? Describe your fields. Does the lines have item numbers? Does the lines have ledger account information?

Comment: That makes sense. I am importing all the invoice information from an oltp system into dynamics. I found that if I import the line item data and the invoice header data into custinvoiceline and custinvoicetable respectively, then open dynamics and post, all is kosher (entries into the custinvoicetrans table are auto generated). So now I simply have to learn how to post thru code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post a "Free text invoice" simply call `custPostInvoiceJob.run()` method.
You will have have to make the object first, then call a method with your newly created `CustInvoiceTable` record.

In X++:

```
custPostInvoiceJob = new CustPostInvoiceJob();
custPostInvoiceJob.updateQueryBuild(custInvoiceTable);
custPostInvoiceJob.run();
```

You will have to translate that into Business Connector calls in your preferred language.

Comment: Hi Jan,
Just wondering what the 'updateQueryBuild' part does - that is a bit I left out.

Comment: Look in the code!
It updates its query to select your `custInvoiceTable` only.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's actually as easy as it should be.

After the insert statement, simply use the get_Field call:

axRecord.Insert();
recID = (long)axRecord.get_Field("RECID");

You insert the line items in the CUSTINVOICELINE table (which uses a PARENTRECID), then upon posting the items get inserted into the CUSTINVOICETRANS table linked to the appropriate invoice number.

I hope this saves someone from having to work this out themselves.

Steve